# Using define_method in Ruby on Rails view helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, components, metaprogramming, helper

I am creating a component library in Rails using view partials. I would like for each component partial defined in `/app/views/components` to have a corresponding helper method for rendering the component. Here is the ComponentHelper code that is not working:

```
*/app/views/components/_navigation.haml*
  ...navigation view partial...

*/app/helpers/components_helper.rb*
module ComponentsHelper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    Dir.entries("#{Rails.root}/app/views/components") do |filename|
      next if filename =~ /^..?$/

      component_name = File.basename(filename, '.haml')[1..-1]
      define_method component_name do |*options, &block|
        component(component_name, *options, &block)
      end
    end
  end

  def component(name, *options, &block)
    render("components/#{name}", *options, &block)
  end
end

*/app/views/home.haml*
.page-home
  = navigation
...rest of view
```

This results in `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method 'navigation' for #<#<Class...`. The method is not being defined. How can I ensure these methods are dynamically created when the helper is included alongside all other Rails helpers?

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: Have you try adding a `helper_method component_name` after defining the method to make it a helper method available on the views? Personally I don't like the idea of a module named "ComponentsHelper" that's actually an ActiveSupport::Concern (concerns should go on the concerns folder, concerns and helper modules are both modules at the end but the convention is different for each one and you are mixing both ideas on one, I guess you want a helper module and not a concern)

Comment: Rails -v 6.0.0.

The `component` helper is already available on all views per Rails inclusion of all helpers in all views. I agree that `ActiveSupport::Concern` has no business here – I was looking to take advantage of `included do` but the `Dir` loop never runs to define the component helper methods.

I have tried manually including the helper in `ApplicationController` after setting `config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false` but manual inclusion is not a solve here.

Comment: Latest: 
This seems to be a problem with `Dir` specifically. Dynamically defining methods using an array literal `[:navigation].each { |name| define_method(name) ... }` works without issue. Very confused why `Dir` is short-circuiting in this context.